# ImportError: 'No module named pyproj'

Tags: python, gdal, shell

I'm running Mac OS X with native Python 2.6.1 installed.

Later today installed GDAL complete pkg, and added the program to the shell path on the terminal with the folowing cmd:

```
~: echo "export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Programs:$PATH" >>.bash_profile
```

Resulting on my bash_file this following line:

```
~: echo "export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Programs:$PATH" >>.bash_profile
```

Now every time I try on terminal to import the pyproj I receive the error:

```
ImportError: No module named pyproj
```

I'm new to Mac's/UNIXs and to OSGgeo in general.

Answer (score 2):

you need to install the Python [pyproj module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj/) which is not in the Proj framework of Kingchaos

Comment: Thanks for the guidance i tried the easy_install pyproj but it fails. Do you have an opinion on how should i install it correctly ?

Comment: An easy_install will have to build a pyproj source distribution for OS X – you'll need a compiler, etc (from XCode) and then you'll need to learn how to make the Kingchaos libs and headers available.